# Authorization with RESTKit and Devise Tokens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restkit, token

New to iOS... I have a Rails/Devise application that is set up with token_authenticatable. I have a tokens controller that returns a token when a valid email and password is posted:

```
URL: http://localhost:3000/tokens.json

Body: email=example@example.com&password=foobar

Response: 
{
  "token": "xyzxyztoken"
}
```

Once created this token grants access to other sections of the site and this works in a test client (RESTClient). I have been stuck for a while connecting to it using RESTKit in iOS.

I create my RKObjectManager in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"http://localhost:3000"];
    self.objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    self.objectManager.client.baseURL = baseURL;

    return YES;
}
```

I have a view controller and when you tap a button it calls this:

```
-(IBAction)btnLoginRegisterTapped:(UIButton*)sender
{
    // get the object manager
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    objectManager.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

    // set mapping
    RKObjectMapping *nameMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Token class]];
    [nameMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"token", @"token", nil];
    [objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:nameMapping forKeyPath:@""];

    // create url
    NSDictionary *queryParams;
    queryParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"example@example.com", @"email", @"foobar", @"password", nil];
    RKURL *URL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURL:[objectManager baseURL] resourcePath:@"/tokens.json" queryParameters:queryParams];

    [objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", [URL resourcePath], [URL query]] delegate:self];
}
```

This is my error:

```
2013-01-10 16:32:55.554 MyApp[69314:14003] response code: 404
2013-01-10 16:32:55.555 MyApp[69314:14003] W restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:300 Unable to find parser for MIME Type 'text/html'
2013-01-10 16:32:55.555 MyApp[69314:14003] W restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:329 Encountered unexpected response with status code: 404 (MIME Type: text/html -> URL: http://localhost:3000/tokens.json?password=foobar&email=example%40example.com -- http://localhost:3000 -- http://localhost:3000)
2013-01-10 16:32:55.556 MyApp[69314:14003] Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain error 4.)
```

This may be a simple question but I am lost. I think I just am not understanding POSTing from iOS in general. One thing to possibly note is that viewing /tokens.json in a browser returns a Routing Error because I do not actually have a view for that:

```
No route matches [GET] "/tokens.json"
```

Anyway the point of all this is for a user to log in and get a token stored and then use it to access other data from the rails app.

Please let me know if more clarification is needed.

Comment: don't think it's a view issue, looks like a routing issue. can you add your routes?

Answer (score 0):

In your rails app, open config/routes.rb

add

```
resources :tokens
```